# Page redirecting back to login page after insert to db

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication

My site has a simplistic login that when you go to an adminSLP page it redirects to the admin login page if the user isnt logged in.  Problem is that when you are logged in to the page and try say inserting a record with the form i posted below it redirects you back to the login page.  I cant see where I am going wrong.

### ADMIN SLP

```
 session_start();
// Call this function so your page
// can access session variables

if ($_SESSION['adminloggedin'] != 1) {
    // If the 'loggedin' session variable
    // is not equal to 1, then you must
    // not let the user see the page.
    // So, we'll redirect them to the
    // login page (login.php).

    header("Location: adminLogin.php");
    exit;
    }
```

### ADMIN LOGIN

```
session_start();
if ($_GET['login']) {
     // Only load the



code below if the GET
 // variable 'login' is set. You will
 // set this when you submit the form

 if ($_POST['adminusername'] == '******'
     && $_POST['adminpassword'] == '*******') {
     // Load code below if both username
     // and password submitted are correct

     $_SESSION['adminloggedin'] = 1;
      // Set session variable

     header("Location: adminSLP.php");
     exit;
     // Redirect to a protected page

 } else echo '<style>#falseLogin{display: block!important;}</style>';
 // Otherwise, echo the error message


}
```

### LOGIN FORM

```
<form method="POST" action="adminLogin.php?login=true" id="adminlogin" style="padding:0">
                    <label for="adminusername">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="adminusername" autocomplete="off"><br/>
                    <label for="adminpassword">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="adminpassword" autocomplete="off" /><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
```

### FORM MADE FOR INSERTING RECORDS TO A DB

```
<form id="trainingForm" method="post" action="" style="display:block;">
                            <div>
                            <h2 id="title" style="color:#c89d64;font-size:36px;font-family: 'RokkittRegular';   margin:0 0 15px; padding:30px 0 30px 0;font-weight:normal;">Add New SLP</h2>

                                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input id="first_name" name="first_name" data-required="false" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">




                                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input id="last_name" name="last_name" data-required="false" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">
                                    <label for="title">Title</label><input id="title" name="title" data-required="false" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">




                                    <label for="user_phone">Phone*</label><input id="user_phone" name="user_phone" type="tel" value="(123) 456-7890" data-required="true" onFocus="if(this.value == '(123) 456-7890') this.value='';">


                                    <label for="user_email">Email*</label><input id="user_email" name="user_email" type="email" value="name@something.com" data-required="true" data-validation="email" onFocus="if(this.value == 'name@something.com') this.value='';">





                                <label for="state_name">License Held In:</label><select name='state_name[]' id="state_name" multiple>
                                    <?php 
                                        $result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM license_state');

                                        $count = 1;
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                        {
                                            echo '<option value=' . $row['state_name'] . '>' . $row['state_name'] . '</option>';

                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </select>

                            <span><label for="isChecked">May we post your information on our site?:</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="isChecked" value="1" checked="checked"><p>Yes</p>
                                        <input type="radio" name="isChecked" value="0"><p>No</p></span>





                                    <label for="asha_number">Asha# (Will Not Be Published)*</label><input id="asha_number" name="asha_number" data-required="true" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">


                                    <label for="practice_name">Practice Name*</label><input id="practice_name" name="practice_name" data-required="true" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">





                                    <label for="practice_location">Practice Location*</label><input id="practice_location" name="practice_location" data-required="true" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text">
                                    <span><label for="telepracticeProvider">Are you a telepractice provider?:</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="telepracticeProvider" id="yes" value="Yes" ><p>Yes</p>
                                        <input type="radio" name="telepracticeProvider" id="no" value="No" checked="checked"><p>No</p></span><br/>


                            <input type="hidden" id='user_id' name='user_id'/>

                                    <br/><button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

                            </div>
                        </form>
```

### insert to db

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {// Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect("Speechvive.db.11357591.hostedresource.com","****","*****!","Speechvive");


        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $state_name = $_POST['state_name'];
        $asha_number = $_POST['asha_number'];
        $practice_name = $_POST['practice_name'];
        $practice_location = $_POST['practice_location'];
        $user_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
        $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $isChecked = $_POST['isChecked'];

        $telepracticeProvider = $_POST['telepracticeProvider'];
        $implodeStates = implode(', ',$state_name);

        $insert = "INSERT INTO users ".
               "(first_name,last_name, title, state_name, asha_number, practice_name, practice_location, user_phone, user_email, isChecked, telepracticeProvider) ".
               "VALUES('$first_name','$last_name', '$title', '$implodeStates', $asha_number, '$practice_name', '$practice_location', '$user_phone', '$user_email', '$isChecked', '$telepracticeProvider')";


               $insertData = mysqli_query( $con,$insert  );
        if(! $insertData )
        {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());  
        }
        mysqli_close($con);?>
            <script>window.location = "http://www.speechvive.com/adminSLP.php";//RELOAD THE CURRENT PAGE</script><?php

                    } else if(isset($_POST['save'])){
            // Create connection
            $con=mysqli_connect("Speechvive.db.11357591.hostedresource.com","Speechvive","Slp2014!","Speechvive");


            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $state_name = $_POST['state_name'];
            $asha_number = $_POST['asha_number'];
            $practice_name = $_POST['practice_name'];
            $practice_location = $_POST['practice_location'];
            $user_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
            $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
            $isChecked = $_POST['isChecked'];

            $telepracticeProvider = $_POST['telepracticeProvider'];
            $implodeStates = implode(', ',$state_name);

            $update = ("UPDATE users SET first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name', title='$title', state_name='$implodeStates', asha_number='$asha_number', practice_name='$practice_name', practice_location='$practice_location', user_phone='$user_phone', user_email='$user_email', isChecked='$isChecked', telepracticeProvider='$telepracticeProvider'  WHERE user_id = $user_id");




                   $updateData = mysqli_query( $con,$update  );
            if(! $updateData )
            {
              die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
            }
            mysqli_close($con);?>
        <script>window.location = "http://www.speechvive.com/adminSLP.php";</script><?php



        }
```

Comment: Where is the code that processes the insert form and does the redirect?

Comment: I will add that right now

Comment: Added I added the redirect to be to the same page so that the new results showed up.

Comment: OT: the insert script should check that you're logged in. I hope this is there and you just didn't copy it.

Comment: It sounds like something is removing `$_SESSION['adminloggedin']`, but I don't see anything in the insert script that would do that.

Comment: It should work I guess I just dont understand

Answer (score 0):

window.location = "http://www.speechvive.com/adminSLP.php";

why did you wrote this in insert to db part.. I think this is creating the problem